# Javascript check for empty array inside empty array?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable

```
var test = [[[]]]
```

And I am wondering if there is an easy way to see if this is empty. While it's technically not empty, it is empty for my instance. Is there a way to check for this?

Comment: Can't you just check if the `.length` of the appropriate array is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just deep flatten the array:

```
var flatten = function(xs) {
  var out = [].concat.apply([], xs)
  return xs.some(Array.isArray) ? flatten(out) : out
}

var isEmpty = function(xs) {
  return !flatten(xs).length
}

isEmpty([[[]]]) //=> true
isEmpty([[[]], [[]]]) //=> true
```

Comment: beat me to it. Yay for functional.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var arr = [[], [], []];
var isEmpty = arr.filter(function (arr) { return arr.length != 0; }).length === 0;
// isEmpty == true

var arr = [[], [], [1,2,3]];
var isEmpty = arr.filter(function (arr) { return arr.length != 0; }).length === 0;
// isEmpty == false
```